# Triying to learning PHP

Tags: php

I'm learning php language as a fresher from 2 or 3 days. I installed XAMPP 1.8.3. and want to run a test.php file from D:\xampp\htdoc. But when im trying to run the file the browser shows a blank page:

The code is:

```
<?php
    echo "This is my first program"
?>
```

Comment: your code has a syntax error, you'd need to turn on the error displaying from the php configuration (google how to do it) and you will see that the parser will scream for syntax error

Comment: @RoyalBg No it doesn't.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol only if the closing tag was on the same line?

Comment: missing semi-colon at end of echo statement?

Comment: Are you running apache and are accessing the file through the browser with `http://localhost/file.php`? If you access the file directly (with `file:///D/xampp/htdocs/file.php`) it will not be processed by PHP

Comment: @TenG `?>` implies `;`. So while not *ideal*, it is not a syntax error ;)

Comment: you missed ; at the end of echo. <?php echo "some thing"; ?>

Comment: [Mistakes Commonly Made by PHP Developers: "Suppressing errors"](http://www.sitepoint.com/7-mistakes-commonly-made-php-developers/#4-suppressing-errors)

Answer (score 3):

You need to load the file through your webserver.

`http://localhost/test.php` not `D:\xampp\htdoc\test.php`.

Loading it directly from the file means the PHP doesn't run, and the browser treats `<?php etc` as an invalid tag (so it doesn't display it).

Comment: Indeed. @Engr you should always *View Source* when working with PHP to see the *generated result*, as opposed to the *rendered result*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your test.php file in **c:/xampp/htdocs** then run the xampp application, click the start button for both apache and mysql, then on your web browser address bar, type localhost/test.php

Answer (score 0):

url:- http://localhost/test.php

your program should be like this

```
<?php 
   echo "This is my first program";
?>
```

always remember semicolon in PHP.